# App view controller not working

Tags: angularjs, controller, frameworks, ng-view

This is very basic and yet my **categories.view.html** inside of my views folder (which consists of lorum ipsum) is not displaying inside of the container div.

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="kB">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <title>Mwiki</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Knowledgebase</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <footer>
    <p> &copy; 2016 Wiki App</p>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/articles.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/categories.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the app.js file which is directly inside the same folder as my index.html

```
var app = angular.module('kB', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/categories', {
    templateUrl: 'views/categories.view.html',
    controller: 'CategoriesCtrl'
  });
}]);

.controller('CategoriesCtrl', [function($scope) {
 console.log($scope);
}]);
```

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon after your config function (or add app before your controller). Also make sure to annotate.

```
var app = angular.module('kB', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/categories', {
    templateUrl: 'views/categories.view.html',
    controller: 'CategoriesCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('CategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 console.log($scope);
}]);
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.